# android, Intercept USSD response returned from the operator. post android 4.2.2

Tags: android, ussd

How to log/intercept data response returned from the operators during USSD session. Can we write our own SSD Client if we can deploy a USSD server on operator end?
It can result in very interesting and useful applications. I have been able to log data prior to 4.2.2 but haven't been successful for the later versions of android.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: There are no APIs on Android to interact with USSD.  Really USSD is a deprecated technology-  it existed to make simple client server calls when phones didn't have data and had to do it via a call.  There is absolutely 0 reason to use USSD when it can use a webservice call instead, except for legacy telecom functionality that hasn't moved over yet,

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I am trying to make this legacy service more interactive for the devices that do not possess an active data connection for the moment. the point being that when there is no data connection user can still navigate & use some of the services even when he lacks data connection. I do understand there are no APIs, Is there any way for me to write such functionality and ship it with my app? or is it just plain impossible? I am willing to dedicate time & go as deep as possible.